# Find probability function and E(X)

Tags: probability

A bowl contains six marbles of which two are green and four are red. The marbles are removed one by one, at random and without replacement. Let $X$ be the number of the drawing at which a red marble is removed for the first time. Find the probability function of $X$, and $\mathbb{E}(X)$

For the probability function, I believe that this question is a geometric distribution, so I have $\mathbb{P}[X=x] = pq^{x-1}$

For $\mathbb{E}(X) = 1/p$ since it's geometric distribution

Am I right? - No

Is it the Hypergeometric distribution?

So E(Y) = nr/N

Comment: What's $p$?  For a geometric distribution you need the trials to be independent.  That's not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not correct; for a geometric distribution, you have to have the same probability of "success" on each draw, whereas here the probability of getting a red depends on the marbles that have been drawn so far.

For instance: the probability that you first get a red marble on the second draw is precisely the probability of getting a green first and then a red, which is $\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: That is true, would it be the hypergeometric distribution then?

Comment: Hypergeometric distribution describes number of success, not number of draws til first success. Don't worry so much about assigning it a name -- there are only three possibilities, and you can write them down explicitly.

Comment: So X = 1 is 4/6, X = 2 is (2/6)(4/5), and X = 3 is (2/6)(1/5)(4/4), but then how would I make a probability function from that?

Comment: That IS your probability mass function.

Comment: Sorry then what would E(x) be?

Comment: The same way as always -- $$\sum_{x\in\Omega}x\cdot P(X=x)$$.